# Serverless framework outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I just want to be able to print out information I need for my app configuration. Starting with the basics: UserPoolId. Output is not working. Anyone know why?

```
service: test-ota-fmw

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: dev

custom:
    stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    variables:
        facebook_app_id: fbappid
        google_app_id: xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

resources:
    # Cognito
    # - ${file(resources/cognito-user-pool.yml)}
    # - ${file(resources/cognito-identity-pool.yml)}
    Resources:
        CognitoUserPool:
            Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
            Properties:
                UserPoolName: mgnio-${self:custom.stage}-user-pool
                UsernameAttributes:
                    - email
                AutoVerifiedAttributes:
                    - email
        CognitoUserPoolClient:
            Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
            Properties:
                ClientName: mgnio-${self:custom.stage}-mobile-app-client
                GenerateSecret: true
                UserPoolId:
                    Ref: CognitoUserPool

    Outputs:
        UserPoolId:
            Value:
                Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

**Output**

Here is the output after running `serverless deploy`

```
Service Information
service: mgnio-ota-fmw
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: mgnio-ota-fmw-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  None
functions:
  None
```

Apparently I have to add more text because it's complaining that my post is mostly code. I don't really know how to explain much further so I'm just going to continue to rant until I have enough text that StackOverflow stops yelling at me. Thanks!

**Update**
I was able to get the output if I ran `serverless deploy -v`.
Is this the expected behavior? Does the Output only display if the `--verbose` flag is set?

Comment: Could you share the log/error message? Apparently it is just not nested correctly, but it is hard to say as it could have been a "copy and past" issue.

Comment: I definitely thought it was a copy/paste issue - i've tried multiple different indentations, but with not luck.

Comment: I was able to get the output if I did `serverless deploy -v`

Comment: That make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the serverless framework display any stack outputs, you need to use the -v or --verbose flag.

```
sls deploy -v
```

or

```
sls info -v
```

See docs [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy/).

Comment: The correct command with the latest version of serverless is `sls info --verbose`.